# Why my android app can't open SQLite database from external storage?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am developing an android app that uses a .db file to request and save app information.

The file that I am using it was ok, but, right now my app can't open the .db file.

Any ideas???

[image: SQLite_exception]

Comment: Have you added permission to write external storage to AndroidManifest ?

Comment: How do you open the database?

Comment: Yes, my android manifest file has the permission.

Comment: This code open my db file: SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(currentDBPath, null,

SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change "Only Read" property in your .db file. Sometimes this problems occurs because somebody changes or manipulates the file.

Now, if you need the file only read, in code when you change "OPEN_READWRITE" to "OPEN_READONLY" property

Comment: Thanks, my db file has read-only property checked. If i use the "OPEN_READONLY" connection flag, i could do the connection, but isn't the approach. By dropping read-only property i can use my file again using the "OPEN_READWRITE" connection flag. But, i don't know why my db file got that property.